# Android Keystore Debug duplicates

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging, google-play-services

**Software:** Eclipse, keytool from java SDK

**Language:** Java

**Platform:** Android

**Searched already:** Google and StackOverFLow, all related finds are about finding or restoring debug keystores, this probleem seems non existing, probably due to a rookie mistake on my part :(

**The problem**

I have the following problem, I have created a game and attached for testing the debug APK SHA1 to Google Play Services so I could test achievements etc. I released the game and that debug SHA1 is still connected, at the time I thought it to be wise so I could keep on testing for future version releases.

Now comes the issue. I am trying to add Google Play Services to an older game I made in the past. Now I can't add the SHA1 code from that debug keystore because it already used by my other application, since I can't seem to delete that debug entry from GooglePlay Services I am stuck with using a different SHA1 code, which means a different debug key(store). However I can't seem to create a different debug store due to the rules that are needed for android SDK, I cannot change the alias, passwords for the debug key... all results in a bad keystore.

How can I change the SHA1 for the debug key which will work with eclipse and android so that I can add the new debug SHA1 to Google Play Services so I can start testing?

Comment: Have you tried to rename the file debug.keystore in the .android directory in your user home dir? Afterwards you should be able create  a fresh debug keystore.

Comment: Yes that did the trick! will be swapping keystore from now on, bit of a shame but at least I can continue. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to rename the file debug.keystore in the .android directory in your user home dir? Afterwards you should be able create a fresh debug keystore.

Afterwards you can try to join the two key-stores using [Portecle](http://portecle.sourceforge.net/) or the keytool command-line tool.